# What is the meaning of ldFlags('-c') in build.gradle?

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle, ldflags

Please help me understand what does ldFlags('-c') in build.gradle in Android Studio mean?

Refer example: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/a498a7809cb7c9ec576b95e797edc4e64777ea00/MoreTeapots/nativeactivity/build.gradle

Comment: I can't tell from your question if you have done any research. I suggest you expand it, try some googling.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the help of the clang llvm compiler: "clang++" like so:

`clang++ -help`, you'll see the possible parameters you can pass:

```
OVERVIEW: clang LLVM compiler

USAGE: clang++ [options] <inputs>

OPTIONS:
  -###                    Print (but do not run) the commands to run 
for this compilation
  --analyze               Run the static analyzer
  -arcmt-migrate-emit-errors
                          Emit ARC errors even if the migrator can     fix them
  -arcmt-migrate-report-output <value>
                          Output path for the plist report
  --cuda-device-only      Do device-side CUDA compilation only
  --cuda-host-only        Do host-side CUDA compilation only
  --cuda-path=<value>     CUDA installation path
  -cxx-isystem <directory>
                          Add directory to the C++ SYSTEM include         search path
  -c                      Only run preprocess, compile, and assemble steps
  ...
  ...
  ...
```

As you can see the explanation for the -c flag is: Only run preprocess, compile, and assemble steps